# Downsized Image gets blurry after being copied to Pasteboard - Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview, image-resizing

I am capturing an image which is then placed in a small imageView. The picture is not blurry in the small imageView, but when I copy it to the clipboard, I am resizing the picture so that it is the same size as the imageView, but now it is blurry when I paste.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        alignment()
        tapToCopy()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

        let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        for device in videoDevices!{
            let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {
                captureDevice = device
            }
        }

        //We will make a new AVCaptureDeviceInput and attempt to associate it with our backCamera input device.
        //There is a chance that the input device might not be available, so we will set up a try catch to handle any potential errors we might encounter.
        var error: NSError?
        var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        do {
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            input = nil
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {
            session!.addInput(input)
            // ...
            // The remainder of the session setup will go here...

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                // ...
                // Configure the Live Preview here...

                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
                videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
                session!.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func alignment() {
        let height = view.bounds.size.height
        let width = view.bounds.size.width

        cameraView.bounds.size.height = height / 10
        cameraView.bounds.size.width = height / 10
        cameraView.layer.cornerRadius = height / 20

        imageView.bounds.size.height = height / 10
        imageView.bounds.size.width = height / 10
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = height / 20
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        videoPreviewLayer!.frame = cameraView.bounds
    }

    @IBAction func takePic(_ sender: Any) {
        if (stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)) != nil {
            let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
            // ...
            // Code for photo capture goes here...
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                // ...
                // Process the image data (sampleBuffer) here to get an image file we can put in our captureImageView

                if sampleBuffer != nil {
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
                    let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
                    // ...
                    // Add the image to captureImageView here...

                    self.imageView.image =  self.resizeImage(image: image, newHeight: self.view.bounds.size.height / 10)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func tapToCopy() {
        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.copyToClipboard(recognizer:)))
        imageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
    }

    func copyToClipboard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIPasteboard.general.image = self.resizeImage(image: imageView.image!, newHeight: self.view.bounds.size.height / 10)
    }

    func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let scale = newHeight / image.size.height
        let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are saying:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
```

Never, never, *never* call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Just pretend it doesn't exist. Always call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead. It takes two extra parameters, which should just about always be `false` and `0`. Things will be a *lot* better when you make that change, because the image will contain scale information that you are currently stripping out.

Another problem is that you are resizing the same image twice in succession — once to display the image in the image view, and then again resizing it some more when you pull the image from the image view and put it on the pasteboard. Don't do that! Instead, store the *original* image, without resizing. Later, you can put *that* on the pasteboard — or resize *the original* image so that you are only resizing it once, totally separate from the image in the image view.